# Using case sensitive match in Case when fucntion

Tags: mysql, sql, case-sensitive

The command

```
case when ltrim(rtrim(City_old)) = ltrim(rtrim(City_New)) then 'Y'
```

doesn't consider case sensitive differences.

Can someone please help me in using a  case-sensitive match in case when function? Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into collations like Latin1_General_CI_AS vs Latin1_General_CS_AS

Comment: What is your table collation set to?

Answer (score 1):

Case sensitivity or insensitivity is based on the string collation defined for your columns. MySQL defaults to a case-insensitive collation, so all comparisons will ignore case by default.

```
mysql> select case when 'city' = 'City' then 'Y' else 'N' end as matches;
+---------+
| matches |
+---------+
| Y       |
+---------+
```

You can make a comparison in a case-sensitive manner by overriding the collation:

```
mysql> select case when 'city' collate utf8mb4_bin = 'City' then 'Y' else 'N' end as matches;
+---------+
| matches |
+---------+
| N       |
+---------+
```

You must choose a collation that is compatible with the character set of the string you are comparing. You can check which compatible collations are supported by your current MySQL instance:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY 
    WHERE character_set_name='utf8mb4';
+------------------------+--------------------+
| COLLATION_NAME         | CHARACTER_SET_NAME |
+------------------------+--------------------+
| utf8mb4_general_ci     | utf8mb4            |
| utf8mb4_bin            | utf8mb4            |
| utf8mb4_unicode_ci     | utf8mb4            |
| utf8mb4_icelandic_ci   | utf8mb4            |
. . .
```

All the collations ending with `_ci` are case-*in*sensitive. The only case-sensitive option above is `utf8mb4_bin`.

Likewise for utf8:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY 
    WHERE character_set_name='utf8';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| COLLATION_NAME           | CHARACTER_SET_NAME |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| utf8_general_ci          | utf8               |
| utf8_bin                 | utf8               |
| utf8_unicode_ci          | utf8               |
| utf8_icelandic_ci        | utf8               |
. . .
```

The choice also depends on the MySQL version you use. They keep introducing new character sets and collations, trying to make MySQL support standards better. For example, in MySQL 8.0, you can use collation `utf8mb4_0900_as_cs`

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html for more details.

Comment: Will `utf8mb4` sort properly?

Comment: @Tomalak, the collation also defines how data is sorted, not the character set.

Comment: Oh, I meant ``utf8mb4_bin`. Would it make sense to make that the column collation or would it be better to use it explicitly for specific comparisons only (because e.g. it would make things sort funny)?

Comment: @Tomalak, Okay so it depends on what you consider sorting properly. With binary collation, sort order would be 'A', 'B', 'C', 'a', 'b', 'c' which might not be what you think is proper.

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitivity in MySQL is often achieved by using the `binary` operator:

```
(case when binary ltrim(rtrim(City_old)) = binary ltrim(rtrim(City_New))
      then 'Y' else 'N'
 end) as is_same
```

This assumes that the original collation of the two strings is the same (which seems reasonable for two columns in the same table).

Comment: This achieves the desired result in many cases, but binary collation is not exactly the same as a case-sensitive collation. You might like to read https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/07/13/no-binary-collations-are-not-case-sensitive/

Comment: @BillKarwin . . . I understand those issues.  `Binary` in MySQL does a byte-by-byte comparison of two strings.  To me, it is a reasonable assumption that if case is different, then other character differences (such as accents) are also different.  Of course, if comparing two strings with different original collations, then all bets are off -- bytes with the same value might be different characters entirely.